# Prevent creation of recurring appointments with no end date

Tags: exchange-2003

We have an ongoing problem where staff book meeting rooms for recurring meetings, but set no end date for the recurrence.  Eventually the member of staff leaves, and the meetings no longer happen, but the rooms remain booked until someone realises this has happened and we manually clean it up.  Is there a way to prevent open ended appointment recurrence, or otherwise manage this better?

We use Exchange 2003.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Microsoft has a solution, as long as your servers and workstations are in a domain where you can apply a GPO to take it away. Good luck, we needed almost the same thing, I was hoping to find a way to turn that off in some folders, not all. But this will work for you to take them all away.

See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2548319

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

A standard Exchange auto accept agent should do it.  The "BookingWindowInMonths" defaults to 12 months.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb123609(EXCHG.65).aspx